# XNA Game Studio Obsolete as of 2013?

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine

I'm not sure If this is the place to ask this but here it goes.

I've been doing game programming in XNA since XNA 2.0, I can also program in C++, C#, Java, and C. I enjoy making games with it and its a great sdk but the problem is the xbox360 is pretty much done.

From what I've read, It seems that XNA is now obsolete and now I'm not sure what sdk to program games in. Now of course I know "you could make your own engine since you know OpenGL/Direct X" yea but that's a shit ton of work.

My Question is what is going to be the next game engine or are there other game engines that you would recommend? I know I used DarkGDK ages ago but I have no idea whats going on with that.

Comment: It seems like Microsoft is pushing C++ to come back ever since the release of Win8, WinRT and Win Phone.

Read here : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173039/is-modern-c-replacing-c-is-microsoft-pushing-developers-to-adopt-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, for an xna fan, look at [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/). It is an open source implementation of xna and is now the [recommended](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobfamiliar/archive/2012/08/01/windows-8-xna-and-monogame-part-1-overview.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0), by Microsoft, game engine for the xna community.

Answer (score 2):

This topic seems to be coming up over and over again. XNA is not obsolete, it is no longer being actively developed. XNA will still be used by many developers for at least a couple more years, but it is definitely not 'obsolete' at this point.

XBox360 is not done. There are still over 40 million Live subscribers and even after the next generation systems are launched, there will still be a sizable market. I am still working on games for XBox360, at least for the next 6 months or so.

As far as game engines, there are quite a few options

Monogame
Unity
JMonkey Engine
LibGDX

Comment: I agree obsolete may be the wrong term but not far off. I can't really see the point in hanging on to something for the next 6 months. Why not use that time preparing for the inevitable.

Comment: Monogame is so close to XNA I can port a game written in XNA to Monogame for PC and OUYA with almost no changes. XBox360 will be a viable marketplace for the next 18 months at the very least. I don't need time to plan to stop using XNA. One day I just won't use it anymore. Today is not yet that day.

Comment: C. Lang, thats what I mean, I want to get a jump on the new thing but from what it seems we're in a transitional period.

Answer (score 1):

Just because XNA is effectively at the end of it's life, that doesn't mean you can't use it. You can still make games for all the existing platforms it supported and it will continue to be useful for that purpose for some time. It isn't so highly-specialized a toolchain that your experience will not be useful as education, either.

For an alternative, check out [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com). Microsoft recently announced [a partnership with Unity3D](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/06/microsoft-boosts-mobile-app-development-and-brings-unity3d-to-xbox-one/) as well.